# How to create FILETIME in Win32?

Tags: winapi, int, filetime

I have a value `__int64` that is a 64-bit `FILETIME` value. `FILETIME` has a `dwLowDateTime` and `dwHighDateTime`. When I try to assign a `__int64` to a `FILETIME` I get a C2440. How do I assign the `__int64` to the `FILETIME`?

Or how do I split the `__int64` so that I can assign the low part to `dwLowDateTime` and the high part to `dwHighDateTime`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the basic outline.

```
__int64 t;
FILETIME ft;

ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)t;
ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)(t >> 32);
```

**NOT RECOMMENDED** approach

```
ft = *(FILETIME *)(&t);
```

It'll work due to the clever arrangement of FILETIME, but the sacrifice in portability and clarity is not worth it.  Use only in times of proven dire need *and* wrap it in asserts to prove it will work.

Answer (score 2):

Mike,

You could use a ULARGE_INTEGER struct to copy the __int64 into the FILETIME:

```
__int64 i64;
ULARGE_INTEGER li;
FILETIME ft;

li.QuadPart = i64;
ft.dwHighDateTime = li.HighPart;
ft.dwLowDateTime = li.LowPart;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
__int64 i;
FILETIME ft;

// From __int64 to FILETIME

ft.dwHighDateTime = (DWORD)(i >> 32);
ft.dwLowDateTime = (DWORD)(i & 0xFFFFFFFF);


// From FILETIME to __int64

i = (ft.dwHighDateTime << 32) + ft.dwLowDateTime;
```

Comment: The mask should be 0xFFFFFFFF.  The second conversion won't work unless you cast ft.dwHighDateTime to __int64 before the << 32.  And adding ft.dwLowDateTime might be a problem if DWORD is signed.